# Find the exact coordinates of turning points of a function $25x^2e^{2x}-16$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have to find the exact coordinates of turning points of a function $25x^2e^{2x}-16$.

Differentiation gives the result of $50x*e^{2x}(1+x)$. Should I just find points where $50x*e^{2x}(1+x)=0$? How to continue?

Comment: $e^{2x}$ is never equal to zero so you many cancel it and you are left with finding $x$ such that $50x(1+x) = 0$, i.e., $x(1+x) = 0$ and thus $x = ...$ or $...$.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{2x}$ becomes insignificant. We'll just look at when $$50x(1+x)$$

Is equal to zero. It is not very hard to tell the solutions are $-1$ and $0$.